# Javascript for simple interest formula

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am totally new on JavaScript, I had written a following script in by which i have to calculate the simple interest. But that script is not working. In which `loan_request_amount` is principle, `loan_request_no_of_emi` is time, `loan_type_interest_rate` is rate .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#loan_request_amount').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = (loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100.toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);

    });

    $('#loan_request_no_of_emi').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = (loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100.toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);
    });

    $('#loan_type_interest_rate').on('input', function() {
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = (loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100.toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

My entire form -

```
<div class="box box-default">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Loan Request</h3>
    <div class="box-body">
      <%= bootstrap_form_for(@loan_request,html: {id: 'loan_request'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <%= f.select :membership_id,all_membership,{label: 'Member',include_blank: 'Select Member'} %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <%= f.select :loan_type_id,all_loan_type,label: 'Loan Type',include_blank: 'Select Loan Type'%>
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <%= f.text_field :amount,label: 'Amount', id: "loan_request_amount" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <%= f.text_field :no_of_emi,label: 'No. of EMI', id: "loan_request_no_of_emi"%>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :emi,label: 'EMI'%>
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :interest_amount,label: 'Interest Amount' , disabled_id: "loan_request_interest_amount" %>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="field">
           <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group required">
              <%= f.text_field :date, label: 'Date', class: 'loan_request'%>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="actions" style="padding: 20px">
            <%= f.submit'Create Loan Request', :class => class_name, data: { disable_with: data_info } %> <!-- | < link_to 'Back', loan_requests_path,class:'btn btn-sm btn-default fa fa-arrow-left' %> -->
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#loan_request_amount').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = (loan_request_amount / loan_request_no_of_emi).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_emi').val(ans);

    });

    $('#loan_request_no_of_emi').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = (loan_request_amount / loan_request_no_of_emi).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_emi').val(ans);
    });
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
    $('#loan_request_amount').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);

    });

    $('#loan_request_no_of_emi').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);
    });

    $('#loan_type_interest_rate').on('input', function() {
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);
   });
  });
  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.loan_request').datepicker({
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '-200:-0',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
     });
</script>

<script>
$("#loan_request").validate({
    rules: {
      "loan_request[membership_id]":{
        required: true,
      },
      "loan_request[amount]":{
        required: true,
        numbersOnly: true,
      },
      "loan_request[loan_type_id]":{
        required: true,
      },
      "loan_request[no_of_emi]":{
        required: true,
        numbersOnly: true,
      },
      "loan_request[date]":{
        required: true,
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "loan_request[membership_id]":{
        required: "Please Select Member",
      },
      "loan_request[amount]":{
        required: "Please Specify Amount",
      },
      "loan_request[loan_type_id]":{
        required: "Please select loan type  ",
      },
      "loan_request[no_of_emi]":{
        required: "Please specify no. of emi  ",
      },
      "loan_request[date]":{
        required: "Please select date  ",
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.css({"color": "red", "font-size": "12px","font-weight" : "normal"})
     error.insertAfter(element.parent(element));
    }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: please use `camelCase` instead of `under_score` naming. please add what does not work.

Comment: @NinaScholz how to write in that i never used JavaScript before

Comment: @AnubhiGolechha The question is not clear! What is not working? Are you getting any error? or specify the case..

Comment: @RajeshKdev no i am not getting any error . I just have to calculate simple interest .

Comment: @AnubhiGolechha Your code is missing this part `ans = ((`. It must have parenthesis correctly in all the places. Something like `((1+2)/3).toFixed()`. Now its resolved you can see/use my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your javascript. a missing parenthese causes the error:

```
 ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
```

Before the method toFixed, there was no parenthese.

A complete and compact solution is:

```
$("#loan_request_amount,#loan_request_no_of_emi,#loan_type_interest_rate").on('input', function() {

  var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
  var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
  var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

  var ans=(loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100;
  if (isNaN(ans)) {
    ans = ""
  }
  else{
    ans =  ans.toFixed(2);
  }
  $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9zctLqz/23/)

Comment: It's more missing parentheses than a missing parenthese... Author needed to wrap all calculations into parentheses before using `.toFixed()` method. i.e. `(1+2)/3.toFixed(2)` won't work while `((1+2)/3).toFixed()` is totally fine. Author also need to make sure to fix all these strings of code.

Comment: @blewherself still not giving any value .

Comment: Please, post your html code so we could get the full picture

Comment: @AnubhiGolechha can you give your html, because I think there's something wrong there

Answer (score 0):

@blewherself Solved the Issue! The Solution that you have is already calculating the Interest amount. But the Problem is, Exception during the calculation. Due to parenthesis

It's more missing parentheses than a missing parenthesis... Author needed to wrap all calculations into parentheses before using .toFixed()

> Method. i.e. (1+2)/3.toFixed(2) won't work while `((1+2)/3).toFixed()`
>   is totally fine. Author also need to make sure to fix all these
>   strings of code.

Just Click on the `Run Code Snippet Button` to see the working solution!

***Here is the working solution:***

```js
$(function(){
    $('#loan_request_amount').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);

    });

    $('#loan_request_no_of_emi').on('input', function() {
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);
    });

    $('#loan_type_interest_rate').on('input', function() {
      var loan_type_interest_rate = parseFloat($('#loan_type_interest_rate').val());
      var loan_request_no_of_emi = parseFloat($('#loan_request_no_of_emi').val());
      var loan_request_amount = parseFloat($('#loan_request_amount').val());

      var ans="";
      if (isNaN(loan_request_amount) || isNaN(loan_request_no_of_emi) || isNaN(loan_type_interest_rate)) {
        ans = ""
      }
      else{
        ans = ((loan_request_amount * loan_request_no_of_emi * (loan_type_interest_rate/12))/100).toFixed(2);
      }
      $('#loan_request_interest_amount').val(ans);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Loan Amount: <input type="text" id="loan_request_amount" placeholder="Loan Amount"><br>
No Of EMI:<input type="text" id="loan_request_no_of_emi" placeholder="No Of Emi"><br>
Interest Rate: <input type="text" id="loan_type_interest_rate" placeholder="Interest Rate"><br>
Interest Amount in Total:<input type="text" disabled id="loan_request_interest_amount" placeholder="Interest Amount">
```

Here is the working [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tef5yus/) link that i used to solve the problem.

Hope this helps.,